# MongoDB get some interval of array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I want to get the specific field of array dynamicaly for example:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]`

In that array first i want to take `14,15,16` after that `[11,12,13]` and go on.

I know that mongoDB has a slice function and it gaves the last element if i give it -1. But when i get the
interval in slice function it only take positive value. So how can i do that?

Note: My array grows dynamically and i dont wan't to learn what is length of the array in each time. Because if i do that, i have to use database 2 times and i guess it is inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 (position -6) ,12,13,14 (position -3) ,15,16]`

I think that something like this would solve your problem:

```js
db.collection.find({},
{
  yourKey: {
    "$slice": [
      -3,
      3
    ]
  }
})
```

Here, counting from the last position, you set your starting point three positions backwards (on the 14 value) and return three elements, in this case, it will return `[14, 15, 16]`.

Then, for the `[11, 12, 13]`:

```js
db.collection.find({},
{
  yourKey: {
    "$slice": [
      -6,
      3
    ]
  }
})
```